# How to set OEM data on movesense device

Tags: movesense

I'm unable to find information on setting custom OEM data on a movesense device.  Is there a way to set custom OEM data (software version, software name, etc) on a device?  If so, how would one go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [App.cpp has macros](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-docs/wiki/EmbeddedSoftware/Getting_started.md):

```
APPINFO_NAME("Sample Plain");
APPINFO_VERSION("1.0.0");
APPINFO_COMPANY("Movesense");
```

This information is returned from GET /Info/App

*Full disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*

Answer (score 1):

Does MDS has some future use of BLE manufacturer data? Currently default is 1, 2, 3, 0. I have added software version as manufacturer data so when scanning devices it is possible to select only correct sensors. By default it could contain firmware version, battery level?